# Storing and accessing deque<vectors> buffer with no additional copying (c++)?

Tags: c++, buffer, deque

How I do store and access deque elements without additional copies?
Like is there a way to point to the deque vectors without removing them until I want to?

Comment: Populate your deque with vector references

Answer (score 0):

Use `deque<>::front()` and `deque<>::back()`

Comment: So do I need to allocate each that I push on with new if I want to do no copy / zero copy methods?

Comment: `front()` and `back()` both return `reference` (or `const_reference`) - no copy is made.